# If value is in array then

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to achieve is a loop that will check if a cell (which will be two letters of the alphabet) is found in a array, if this is the case other stuff will happen.

So far my code looks like:

```
Sub Mortgagee()

    Dim Symbol As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Symbol = Range("C1:C11").Value

    For i = LBound(Symbol, 1) To UBound(Symbol, 1)
        If Symbol.contains("A1") Then
            Range("G1").Copy
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your actual question? When happens when you run this code? And where did you defined "Codes" in "Ubound(Codes,1)"?

Comment: On a one-dimensional array just use `Application.Match` function e.g., `If Not IsError(Application.Match(Symbol, Range("A1").Value, False)) Then ...`

Comment: if you want to know if the array value contains-as opposed to equals-the value in A1 use Instr: `If Instr(1, Symbol(i), Range("A1"), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, `Symbol` is only taking the value of the first cell in the range - in this case, it is just taking the value of whatever is in cell C1.

I'm going to assume that you what you are trying to do is check if the value of a cell exists in an array - not if the cell itself is (which would mean you had an array of cell, or Range, objects).

```
Sub Mortgagee()
     Dim i as Long
     Dim arrSymbol(1 to 11) as String

     For i = 1 to UBound(arrSymbol)
          If arrSymbol(i) = "value to match" Then
               'Do work here
          End If
     Next i

End Sub
```

If you provide more information about the problem, specifically what value(s) you are checking for and also where `Codes` came from and what it is then I can help you out some more.

Comment: Codes was a typo, was meant to say symbol